# Downloading all Tweets about certain subject in Python

Tags: python, twitter, bigdata

Im doing Twitter sentiment research at the moment. For this reason, I'm using the Twitter API to download all tweets on certain keywords. But my current code is taking a lot of time to create a large datafile, so I was wondering if there's a faster method.

This is what Im using right now:

```
__author__ = 'gerbuiker'

import time

#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream


#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_token_secret = "XXXXXXXX"
consumer_key = "XXXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

     def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        #print data
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        print tweet

        saveThis = str(time.time())+ '::'+ tweet #saves time+actual tweet
        saveFile = open('twitiamsterdam.txt','a')
        saveFile.write(saveThis)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
    except BaseException, e:
        print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
        time.sleep(5)

def on_error(self, status):
    print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

#This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)

#This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'Amsterdam'
stream.filter(track=['KEYWORD which i want to check'])
```

This gets me about 1500 tweets in one hour, for a pretty popular keyword (Amsterdam). Does anyone now a faster method in Python?

To be clear: I want to download all tweets on a certain subject for last month/year for example. So the newest tweets don't have to keep coming in, the most recent ones for a period would be sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean *"faster"*? How could you capture an hour's worth of tweets in less than an hour?!

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous.  Are you suggesting that this code takes too long to process tweets?  That it's missing tweets it should have captured?  How do you know that there were more than 1500 tweets in an hour with that keyword?  One note though: use the `with` context when opening a file - Google is your friend here.  As it is now if there's an error after opening the file but before it closes, the file is never closed and may wind up in a bad state.

Comment: Sorry! I mean that I want to download tweets on a certain subject from a month or year ago until now for example.

Answer (score 0):

I need something similar to this for an academic research.
We're you able to fix it?
Would it be possible to specify a custom range of time from which to pull the data?

Sorry for asking here, but couldn't send you private messages.